# Orbeon forms and mysql: JDBC naming context problem

Tags: mysql, forms, jdbc, orbeon

I am trying to set up orben forms with mysql. I've been following these steps:

-Created schema "Orben" with the associated user "Orbeon"

-Donwloaded the mysql java jdbc connector and stored it in tomcat/lib

-Added the database data to tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            poolPreparedStatements="true"
            username="orbeon"
            password="orbeon"
            url="jdbc:mysql://IP_ADRESS_OF_MYSQL_SERVER:3306/orbeon"/>
```

-Added the following lines to properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.*" value="/fr/service/mysql"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>
```

However, when I start tomcat and access Form Builder, I got the following error in orbeon.log:

```
2011-04-14 14:36:11,652 ERROR SQLProcessor  - PreparedStatement:null
    2011-04-14 14:36:11,662 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at oxf:/apps/fr/persistence/mysql/search.xpl (executing XSLT transformation)
    *javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: El nombre jdbc no este asociado a este contexto*
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.DatabaseContext.getConnection(DatabaseContext.java:56)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessorInterpreterContext.getConnection(SQLProcessorInterpreterContext.java:334)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.interpreters.QueryInterpreter.end(QueryInterpreter.java:173)
        at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler.endElement(SQLProcessor.java:540)
...
```

The spanish sentence translation is "The jdbc name is not linked to this context".

Going down the log, we can also find:

```
2011-04-14 16:08:50,877 ERROR XFormsServer  - xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException:  (processing submission response): xforms:submission for submission id: search-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 500
null, line -1, column -1: xforms:submission for submission id: search-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 500
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission.getReplacer(XFormsModelSubmission.java:672)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1.call(RegularSubmission.java:96)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1.call(RegularSubmission.java:68)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission.submitCallable(BaseSubmission.java:222)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission.connect(RegularSubmission.java:119)
...
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I've reached a dead end. I've read the related posts but I couldn't find any information that could solve the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Álvaro

References:

http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers
http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/contributor-guide/form-builder-integration-notes

Software versions:

- Mysql 5.1.37-1
- Orbeon Forms 3.9.0.rc1.201103220245 CE
- mysql-connector-java-508-bin.jar
- Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.32

(After avernet answer)
I added a context to the database resource in server.xml. Tomcat lies in "C:\tomcat" and orbeon.war is at "C:\tomcat\webapps\orbeon.war"

The complete (and incorrect) server.xml is as following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

<Context path="/orbeon" docBase="/webapps/" reloadable="false" override="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                poolPreparedStatements="true"
                username="orbeon"
                password="orbeon"
                url="jdbc:mysql://vmpresiges:3306/orbeon"/>
</Context>
  </GlobalNamingResources>



  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

(After avernet answer#2) the correct server.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>



  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->
    <Context path="/orbeon" docBase="/orbeon" reloadable="false" override="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
        <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
                driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                poolPreparedStatements="true"
                username="orbeon"
                password="orbeon"
                url="jdbc:mysql://IP_ADDRESS:3306/orbeon"/>
    </Context>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come down to the data source not being found in JNDI. Now both your `<Resource>` in server.xml and the `oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource` property look correct. I am wondering if `<Resource>` is maybe not in the right place in Tomcat's server.xml, and hence that name is not visible to the Orbeon web app. I would recommend you put that `<Resource>` inside the `<Context >` for the Orbeon web app, for instance (which is what I have locally for a test database):

```
<Context path="/orbeon" docBase="/path/to/orbeon-war" reloadable="false" override="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        poolPreparedStatements="true"
        username="orbeon"
        password="orbeon"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Hi avernet. Thanks for your response. I didn't have any context at all, but I added the context line and I am still getting the same error. I will paste the complete "server.xml" in the original post. Thank you.

Comment: @Álvaro, the `<Context>` element goes into the `<Host name="localhost">` instead of `<GlobalNamingResources>`. You'll let us know if it works out after doing this change.

Comment: Hi avernet.Thanks a lot, after moving the <Context> element it's working now.

Comment: Where to create the new properties-local.xml in tomcat/webbapps/orbeon as of now I created the file in tomcat/webbapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/properties-local.xml but still all forms are save in default DB.

Comment: @Prathyush See my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/6361071/5295 (and I suggest we continue the "discussion" there.)