# Orbeon Nightly Build is not letting me connect to MYSQL database

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to update existing orbeon installation with nightly build and use the existing MYSQL database, but the new version is not letting me connect to mysql databse. It is defaulted to eXist database.

I set the property `oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource` to `mysql`:

`<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>`

but no use.

can some one please help me with this connection issue.

Comment: please use the {} to format code snippets, otherwise they aren't visible to other people.

Answer (score 0):

The way you configure which persistence layer to use changed after the 3.9 release to give you more flexibility, specifically to allow you to have different apps stored in different schemas of the same database. So most likely, you'll just need to change your properties in `properties-local.xml`. For more about this change, see [Form Runner persistence layer configuration](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/310#TOC-Form-Runner-persistence-layer-confi).

Comment: My current orbeon is 3.9 version and it connects to mySql DB.

Comment: Right now we are using Orbeon 3.9 PE version and it works with MySql database. '<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.service.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>
<property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.*" value="/fr/service/mysql"/>'.

Comment: @avernet, You are right with Orbeon 3.9 PE version and it works with MySql database. but  ** Now the issue is with the Orbeon nightly build(06.14.2011) **  We set the values as you said in properties-local.xml it is not connecting to MySql database.

Comment: @rcreddi, so essentially, if your datasource is `jdbc/mysql`, with the nightly builds, defining the property `<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="oracle"/>` in your `properties-local.xml` should be enough. Is that what you have?

Comment: Hi All, I am using Orbeon4-9.0. I add the following content in server.xml file.<Context path="/orbeon" docBase="orbeon"debug="5" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
   <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"poolPreparedStatements="true"username="orbeon" password="orbeon"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon"/></Context>and I created a new"properties-local.xml" file in following path tomcat7/webapps/orboen/WEB-INF but still connected to default DB.

Comment: I need to connect MySQL DB. But still Orbeon connected to the default DB. Some one please help me.

Comment: @Prathyush Did you also change the `properties-local.xml`? And in case you haven't read this already, you can find more information about the whole setup on https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Relational-Database-Setup.

Comment: @Avennet :Where to create the new properties-local.xml in tomcat/webbapps/orbeon as of now I created the file in tomcat/webbapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/properties-local.xml but still all forms are save in default DB

Comment: @Prathyush The `properties-local.xml` goes in the `webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/config/properties-local.xml`. You'll let us know if this works for you.